# Ruby on Rails User Management Engine/Framework? (with web pages)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authorization, user-management

There are quite a few post/recommendations re Rails authorization plugins.  What I'm asking here however is whether there is a popular/good Ruby on Rails Engine (or framework) that includes the user interface pages as well (and controllers/models etc).  So something one could integrate in (Engine) or use as a starting point that includes:

- sign up (e.g. user creates a login, then email is sent with activation link)
- authentication
- authorization
- User interface allowing user to:

  - change password
- Delegated Administration (Optional)

  - supports multiple/separate companies/groups using the same application
  - Admin User for Company/Group X, and allocate access to Person Y (create a new user)
  - UI to allow user to perform these functions

I threw in the last delegated administration as an optional extra.  If there a good/populate product that doesn't have this I'd rather hear about it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I think you can get most of the way there using [clearance](http://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance), but you'll need to implement authorization separately.

Clearance is a Rails engine that will give you

- sign_up
- Authorization
- Forgot your password
- Remember me
- Very easy to customize

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using Authlogic(for authentication) and Lockdown(for roles) in combination.
They are both in a stable state and work well!

Just have a look at the authlogic/lockdown tutorial at http://stonean.com/page/lockdown-with-authlogic.

The Authlogic example application available on github may show you some sample code for registration, changing password etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) seems to be a current big one that basically supports everything under the sun.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that something with all that is available.
A combination from acts_as and
 acts_as_authenticated and LoginEngine and maybe 
http://code.google.com/p/rails-authorization-plugin/

Could probably be made into something you like to have.

Regards